# Write JWT Authorization for CRUD using Azure function in Node js

Tags: node.js, jwt, azure-functions

When the user logs in successfully, it provides the JWT token.

The httptrigger1 folder, index.js The code is as below:

```
const response = require("../traits/api_response");
const Database = require("../model/database");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const config = require("../config/config");

module.exports = async function (context, req) {
  context.log("JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

  var raw_data = req.body;

  try {
    // await need to send the data here
    const database = new Database(config);
    const email = raw_data.email;
    const password = raw_data.password;

    const user = await database.findEmail(email);
    //console.log(user);
    if (user && (await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password))) {
      const token = jwt.sign(
        { user: user.userId, email },
        `${process.env.TOKEN_KEY}`,
        {
          expiresIn: "12h",
        }
      );
      console.log("It find user email successfully.");
      context.res = {
        status: 200,
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: response.success(
          token,
          `Successfully going into the MS Sql server to get login information`
        ),
      };
    }
    database.disconnect();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    context.res = {
      status: 500,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: response.error(array_data, `${err.message}`),
    };
  }
};
```

That httptrigger1 folder, function.json

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": ["post"],
      "route": "login"
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    }
  ]
}
```

I create another endpoint with azure function which will have to accept the authentication in order to fetch the data from the system. In other words, I create another get endpoint which needs to be authorization with login JWT.

I created middleware folder and middleware/auth.js. The code is as below:

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

const verifytoken = (req, res, next) => {
  const token = req.headers["x-auth-token"];

  if (!token) {
    res.status(403).send("A token is required for authentication");
  }
  try {
    const user = jwt.verify(token, process.env.TOKEN_KEY);
    req.user = user;
    console.log("middleware is working");
    return next();
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(401).send("Invalid Token");
  }
};

module.exports = verifytoken;
```

Another endpoint httptrigger2 folder, function.json

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": ["get"],
      "route": "getuser/{userId}"
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    }
  ]
}
```

In httptrigger2 folder, index.js.

```
const response = require("../traits/api_response");
const Database = require("../model/database");
const config = require("../config/config");
const verifytoken = require("../middleware/auth");

module.exports = async function (context, req) {
  context.log("JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
  try {
    const { userId } = context.bindingData;
    console.log("Getting from the localhostlink: ", userId);
    if (!userId) {
      context.res = {
        status: 400,
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: response.error([], `User ID muct put!`),
      };
      return;
    }

    const database = new Database(config);
    if (verifytoken()) {
      const user = await database.findID(userId);

      context.res = {
        status: 200,
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: response.success(
          user,
          `Successfully going into the MS Sql server to get login information.`
        ),
      };
      database.disconnect();
    }
  } catch (err) {
    context.res = {
      status: 200,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: `${err.message}`,
    };
  }
};
```

the output in postman is under as below;

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'headers')
```

Explanation >>>
My above code did not run with JWT authorization. It did provide the JWT token when user login successfully, but it did not protect with JWT for the other endpoint which is 'getuser/{userId}' function. I did make the middle ware to verify token and it called in endpoint function, however, it did not work.
Could you please help me how can i write this?

Comment: refer this for JWT in [azurefunction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/ms-identity-docs-code-javascript/ms-identity-docs-code-functions-nodejs/)

Comment: will give a sample example to use.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const  jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
module.exports = async  function  (context,  req)  {
try  {
const  decodedToken = jwt.decode(req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1]);
with a greeting message and default 200 status code
status code
context.res =
decodedToken.scp.split(" ").indexOf("Greeting.Read") > -1
? {
body:  "Hello, world. You were able to access this because you provided a valid access token with the Greeting.Read scope as a claim.",
}
: {  body:  "Missing required scope.",  status:  403  };

}  catch (error) {
context.res = {  body:  "Invalid token.",  status:  403  };
}
};
```

[image]

[image]

**Note:**

Function app authentication does not, as of the time of this writing, support a local development environment that is equivalent to the on-Azure runtime. This can still be run **locally** using func start, however, Azure's Function app service's authentication features won't be used, and all JWT token validation for authorization (signature, iss, exp, AUD) will be disregarded.From this [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/ms-identity-docs-code-javascript/ms-identity-docs-code-functions-nodejs/).

Another method is adding a user and accessing it.

```js
const  accessToken = jwt.sign(

{  "username":  foundUser.username  },

process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET,

{  expiresIn:  '30s'  }

);

const  refreshToken = jwt.sign(

{  "username":  foundUser.username  },

process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET,

{  expiresIn:  '1d'  }

);

const  otherUsers = usersDB.users.filter(person  =>  person.username !== foundUser.username);

const  currentUser = { ...foundUser,  refreshToken  };

usersDB.setUsers([...otherUsers,  currentUser]);

await  fsPromises.writeFile(

path.join(__dirname,  '..',  'model',  'users.json'),

JSON.stringify(usersDB.users)

);

res.json({  'success':  `User ${user} is logged in!`  });
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

Referred from this [git](https://github.com/gitdagray/user_auth).